# Control Google Map V3 overlays

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What I'm trying to create is a form which toggles branch area coverage on and off. Tick a checkbox next to a branch name, area appears on the map. So the areas toggle on and off.

Generated the area like so:

```
// Construct the polygon.
branchcoverage = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coveragecoords[0]["coords"], //Pull in x,y polygon co-ords
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
});

branchcoverage.setMap(mymap);
branchcoverage.setMap(null); //Turn off overlay to test controls
```

This could be where I'm slipping up, is it possible to reference/control a googlemap via a standard html form? By that I don't mean a custom html form embedded into/onto the map (like this example - http://predict.habhub.org/), a separate html form not inside the DIV map canvas. Even getting a simple onclick to interact with the map would be a great starting point:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="google.maps.branchcoverage.setMap(mymap);">Show coverage</a>
```

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Many thanks for your time reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a href="#" id="my-element">Show coverage</a>
```

You would want to use this function to interact with the dom. The [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple) docs go through most of this stuff

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('my-element').click(function(){
    branchcoverage.setMap(mymap);
}));
```

Comment: You beauty! Thanks Craicerjack, that's pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses your original inline onclick event handler, with one short function that can be used to toggle all markers, polylines, or polygons on a map.

```
function togglePoly(polyname){
    if (polyname == null || undefined || '') return;
    else {
        if (polyname.getVisible()) polyname.setVisible(false);
        else polyname.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Inline use...

```
<a href="#" id="my-element" onclick="togglePoly('branchcoverage');">Show/Hide coverage</a>
```

Script use...

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('my-element').click(togglePoly('branchcoverage')));
```

This works because Google maps markers and polys are extensions of the Google MVC object, and therefore can use all the methods available for the MVC object as well.

Comment: Just had an Epiphany ;-) (I know you've heard that before). Many thanks for your time and the insight, opens up a few more options.